# Каким образом можно реализовать распознавание русского языка(speech-to-text) в react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Подскажите, пожалуйста, через что можно сделать speech-to-text на react-native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const startSpeechToText = async () => {
   await Voice.start("ru");
};
```

Используйте данную функцию для начала записи, принимает аргумент языка

Comment: Извини, забыл добавить ссылку на библиотеку) https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice